# SYSVAD - multiple mic and speaker pairs

Tags: c++, windows, audio, kernel, driver

after installing Microsoft Sample audio driver (SYSVAD/TabletAudioSample)
I see multiple(around 4-5) playback & recording devices appearing in list of output/input audio devices

I don't want multiple devices, I just want 1 device in playback & 1 device in recording.

How to clean up the SYSVAD driver code to achieve this ?
Where to make changes in code to make sure unnecessary mic/speaker pairs doesn't appear?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can somebody give some guidance on this? Few pointers will help a lot. Thank you